# php count and get last record in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, count, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to be able to count total events for a given day (today) for a specific venue.
Using 24 hour time,
I tried to find last event of the day within the foreach loop and then when the end_time of last event of the day is less than now, show text, "All scheduled events have concluded for today."

my problem is that the xml data includes all events in all rooms for 14 days and I'm not getting the correct count.
I have a few if statements within the foreach to whittle it down....

if xml space id == room id, then
if xml event start_date equals today, then
if ($i < $numItems)
if event end time is greater than now,
show those events

I need the count of records when those conditions are met...when events are for today's date and in the same room as the roomID that gets passed thru url.
Putting my $numItems = $count($arr) before the foreach counts too many records and putting a count within foreach always returns only count of 1.

```
$arr = $this->data['events'];
$numItems = count($arr);
$i = 1;
foreach ($arr as $key => $reservation){
if ((int)$reservation->space_reservation->space_id == $roomID) 
{
//test today's date
        $resDT = date('m/d/y',strtotime($reservation->reservation_start_dt));
        if ($resDT == date('m/d/y'))
            {
            if ($i < $numItems)
            {
            $repst = substr($reservation->event_start_dt,11,5);
            $repet = substr($reservation->event_end_dt,11,5);

                if ( (date('H:i',strtotime($repet))) > (date('H:i')) )
                    {
                    echo '<h2>' .$reservation->event_name. '</h2> ';
                    echo '<span class="dates">' .date('m/d/y',strtotime($reservation->event_start_dt)). ' </span> ';
                    echo '<span class="times">' .date('g:i a',strtotime($repst)). ' - ';
                    echo date('g:i a',strtotime($repet)). '</span> ';
                    echo '<br />';
                    } // ends if event end date has passed

            //echo '<span style="color:#FFF200;">'.$i.'</span>';
            echo '<br />';
            }
//if $i equals last record
            elseif ($i === $numItems) {
                // test if last event ends show
                if ( (date('g:i a',strtotime($repet))) < (date('g:i: a')) ){
                echo '<span style="color:#FFF200;">All scheduled meetings/events have concluded for today. </span><br /><br />';
                }
            }
            $i++;
            } // ends if

    } // ends if
} // ends for each
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will print one of these:

1. All the unfinished events for today for the given room only;
2. The "All scheduled events have concluded for today." if there are none left.

I added two counters for you to be able to use as you need:

- **$totalEventsToday** - counts all the events scheduled for today on the given room;
- **$unfinishedEventsToday** - counts the events scheduled for today on the given room whose end date/time hasn't passed yet.

So here's the code:

```
$today                 = date('m/d/y');
$events                = $this->data['events'];
$totalEventsToday      = 0;
$unfinishedEventsToday = 0;

// Check all reservations/events
foreach ($events as $reservation) {

    // Process reservation/events for the given room only
    if ((int) $reservation->space_reservation->space_id == $roomID) 
    {
        // Process reservation/events for today only
        $resDT = date('m/d/y', strtotime($reservation->reservation_start_dt));
        if ($resDT == $today)
        {
            $totalEventsToday++;

            $repst = substr($reservation->event_start_dt,11,5);
            $repet = substr($reservation->event_end_dt,11,5);

            // Process unfinished event
            if ((date('H:i',strtotime($repet))) > (date('H:i')))
            {
                $unfinishedEventsToday++;

                echo '<h2>' .$reservation->event_name. '</h2> ';
                echo '<span class="dates">' .date('m/d/y',strtotime($reservation->event_start_dt)). ' </span> ';
                echo '<span class="times">' .date('g:i a',strtotime($repst)). ' - ';
                echo date('g:i a',strtotime($repet)). '</span> ';
                echo '<br />';
            } // ends if unfinished event
         } // ends if today
    } // ends if room
} // ends for each

// Test if there aren't any unfinished events left for today
if (!$unfinishedEvents){
    echo '<span style="color:#FFF200;">All scheduled meetings/events have concluded for today. </span><br /><br />';
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks! You had $unfinishedEventsToday =0; which I changed to $unfinishedEvents to match the code later on.

Comment: @sloga, thanks for picking it up, just corrected to code so the variable names would match :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am not really sure where your problem is.  You can simply add a counter like I have done with `$currentEvents` below.

```
$arr = $this->data['events'];
$numItems = count($arr);
$currentEvents = 0;
$i = 1;
foreach ($arr as $key => $reservation){
if ((int)$reservation->space_reservation->space_id == $roomID) 
{
//test today's date
        $resDT = date('m/d/y',strtotime($reservation->reservation_start_dt));
        if ($resDT == date('m/d/y'))
            {
            if ($i < $numItems)
            {
            $repst = substr($reservation->event_start_dt,11,5);
            $repet = substr($reservation->event_end_dt,11,5);

                if ( (date('H:i',strtotime($repet))) > (date('H:i')) )
                    {
                    $currentEvents++;
                    echo '<h2>' .$reservation->event_name. '</h2> ';
                    echo '<span class="dates">' .date('m/d/y',strtotime($reservation->event_start_dt)). ' </span> ';
                    echo '<span class="times">' .date('g:i a',strtotime($repst)). ' - ';
                    echo date('g:i a',strtotime($repet)). '</span> ';
                    echo '<br />';
                    } // ends if event end date has passed

            //echo '<span style="color:#FFF200;">'.$i.'</span>';
            echo '<br />';
            }
//if $i equals last record
            elseif ($i === $numItems) {
                // test if last event ends show
                if ( (date('g:i a',strtotime($repet))) < (date('g:i: a')) ){
                echo '<span style="color:#FFF200;">All scheduled meetings/events have concluded for today. </span><br /><br />';
                }
            }
            $i++;
            } // ends if

    } // ends if
} // ends for each
```